# Why do people change my answers to these questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Every time I answer people change it.  It's like you cannot control your answers!

Comment: Hi, as this is a question about the site itself (and not about games) I've moved it to our meta site.

Comment: See someone is editing my question now

Comment: Arqade is a Q&A website where [users can edit each other's questions and answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), it's part of our whole premise. We do make an effort to only edit posts for the better, though :)

Comment: Well they edit the title

Comment: From your [profile page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/30068/unknown), I only see one answer, and as far as I can tell, it hasn't been edited.  Is there a second profile that you're using?

Comment: Yes, and we allow users to edit the title, too. Again, it's not out of spite. Those users are genuinely trying to make the posts better - for better Googlability, for instance, or to fix grammatical error, or just to remove irrelevant parts. As better-quality posts have a better chance of getting upvoted and accepted, those users are actually investing their times for your sake. Please don't take it as an insult - that's not where it's coming from.

Comment: And as a matter of fact, you can also suggest improvements for other people posts yourself - if your suggestions are accepted, you actually gain reputation points yourself! And if the suggestions are rejected you lose nothing, and you also usually get an informative reason as well as to why the suggestion was rejected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The edit suggestion that you made wasn't really acceptable.  Edit suggestions such as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/6294) do nothing but deface the question.

Also, let me be the first to welcome you to Arqade!  This place works very differently than a forum.  I would suggest you give the FAQ a quick skim to hit the high points.  Essentially, anybody can edit anyone else's questions and answers.  Anyone under 2,000 rep, though, needs it approved by someone that has that amount.  This is to prevent exactly what you did.

If we edit your answer, it's to make it *better*.  We're not doing it because we're trying to troll you; we're improving the formatting and clarifying your question or answer.

Another side point, because it looks you're trying to contribute, and it's getting removed.  If what you are posting as an answer is just a "Me, too!" or "Thanks, that worked!", it's going to get removed.  Mostly because the space where you're posting it, is reserved for answers to the original question.  Things like that just increase the amount of processing that's needed to get to an actual helpful answer.

I would suggest that you find a question that you *can* answer, and contribute by answering it.  Try not to duplicate what's already been said (and do NOT just copy and paste something from somewhere), but if you can add in information that isn't already there, you'll get upvotes!

Comment: Oh so that's why